# jQuery - File uploader with multiple instances

Tags: jquery

I am trying to convert the working codepen into jQuery from Javascript in order to run multiple instances of the image uploader. The problem may be my attempt to iterate over each `.item` but also may be in the conversion from `addEventListener` to `.on()`.
https://codepen.io/moofawsaw/pen/dyPdpGy

> Where did I go wrong in my conversion?

Here is my attempted jQuery conversion (not working):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function ekUpload() {
    var $item = $(".item");

    function fileDragHover(e) {
      var fileDrag = $item.find(".file-drag");

      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();

      fileDrag.className =
        e.type === "dragover" ? "hover" : "modal-body file-upload";
    }

    async function fileSelectHandler(e) {
      // Fetch FileList object
      var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

      // Cancel event and hover styling
      fileDragHover(e);

      // Process all File objects
      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        const f = files[i];
        if (await hasAlpha(f)) {
          console.log("Selected image is transparent");
          parseFile(f);
          uploadFile(f);
        } else {
          console.log("Selected image is not transparent");
          $item.find(".response").removeClass("hidden");
          $item.find(".error-image").removeClass("hidden");
          $item.find(".file-image").addClass("hidden");
          output(
            '<strong class="warning">Image background is not transparent</strong>'
          );
        }
      }
    }
    // Output
    function output(msg) {
      // Response
      var m = $item.find(".messages");
      m.innerHTML = msg;
    }

    function Init() {
      console.log("Upload Initialised");

      var fileSelect = $item.find(".file-upload"),
        fileDrag = $item.find(".file-drag"),
        submitButton = $item.find(".submit-button");

      fileSelect.on("change", function(e) {
        fileSelectHandler(e);
      });

      // Is XHR2 available?
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      if (xhr.upload) {
        // File Drop
        fileDrag.on("change dragleave", function(e) {
          fileDragHover(e);
        });
        fileDrag.on("drop", function(e) {
          fileSelectHandler(e);
        });
      }
    }

    function hasAlpha(file) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let hasAlpha = false;
        const canvas = $item.find("canvas");
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        const img = new Image();
        img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
        img.onerror = reject;
        img.onload = function() {
          canvas.width = img.width;
          canvas.height = img.height;

          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
          const imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
            .data;

          for (let j = 0; j < imgData.length; j += 4) {
            if (imgData[j + 3] < 255) {
              hasAlpha = true;
              break;
            }
          }
          resolve(hasAlpha);
        };
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      });
    }

    function parseFile(file) {
      console.log(file.name);
      output("<strong>" + encodeURI(file.name) + "</strong>");

      // var fileType = file.type;
      // console.log(fileType);
      var imageName = file.name;

      var isGood = /\.(?=svg|jpg|png|jpeg)/gi.test(imageName);
      if (isGood) {
        $item.find(".start").addClass("hidden");
        $item.find(".response").removeClass("hidden");
        $item.find(".notimage").addClass("hidden");
        // Thumbnail Preview
        $item.find(".error-image").addClass("hidden");
        $item.find(".file-image").removeClass("hidden");
        $item.find(".file-image").src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      } else {
        $item.find(".error-image").removeClass("hidden");
        $item.find(".file-image").addClass("hidden");
        $item.find(".notimage").removeClass("hidden");
        $item.find(".start").removeClass("hidden");
        $item.find(".response").addClass("hidden");
        $item.find(".file-upload-form").reset();
      }
    }

    function uploadFile(file) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        fileInput = $this.find(".class-roster-file"),
        fileSizeLimit = 1024; // In MB

      if (xhr.upload) {
        // Check if file is less than x MB
        if (file.size <= fileSizeLimit * 1024 * 1024) {
          // File received / failed
          xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
              // Everything is good!
              // document.location.reload(true);
            }
          };

          // Start upload
          xhr.open(
            "POST",
            document.getElementById("file-upload-form").action,
            true
          );
          xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.size);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
          xhr.send(file);
        } else {
          output("Please upload a smaller file (< " + fileSizeLimit + " MB).");
        }
      }
    }

    // Check for the various File API support.
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
      Init();
    } else {
      $item.find("file-drag").css("display", "none");
    }
  }
  $(".item").each(function() {
    ekUpload();
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto");
html,
body,
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #454cad;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

p {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #5f6982;
}

.uploader {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.uploader label {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 3px solid #eee;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.uploader label:hover {
  border-color: #454cad;
}

.uploader label.hover {
  border: 3px solid #454cad;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 6px #eee;
}

.uploader label.hover #start i.fa {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  transform: scale(0.8);
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.uploader #start {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

.uploader #start.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.uploader #start i.fa {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.uploader #response {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

.uploader #response.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.uploader #response #messages {
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

.uploader #file-image {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto .5rem auto;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 180px;
}

.uploader #file-image.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.uploader #notimage {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

.uploader #notimage.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.uploader progress,
.uploader .progress {
  display: inline;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 180px;
  height: 8px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.uploader .progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.uploader .progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #393f90 0%, #454cad 50%);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.uploader .progress[value]::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #393f90 0%, #454cad 50%);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.uploader input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}

.uploader div {
  margin: 0 0 .5rem 0;
  color: #5f6982;
}

.uploader .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: .5rem .5rem 1rem .5rem;
  clear: both;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: initial;
  border: none;
  border-radius: .2rem;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #454cad;
  border-color: #454cad;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.uploader input[type="file"],
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.warning {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Upload  -->
<div class="item">
  <form class="uploader file-upload-form">
    <input class="file-upload" type="file" name="fileUpload" accept="image/*" />
    <label for="file-upload" class="file-drag">
    <img src="#" alt="Preview" class="file-image hidden">
    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/online-states/150/Snooze-512.png" class="error-image hidden">
    <div class="start">
      <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <div>Select a file or drag here</div>
      <div class="notimage hidden">Please select an image</div>
    </div>
    <div class="response hidden">
      <div class="messages"></div>
    </div>
  </label>
  </form>
  <div class="filename"></div>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <form class="uploader file-upload-form">
    <input class="file-upload" type="file" name="fileUpload" accept="image/*" />
    <label for="file-upload" class="file-drag">
    <img src="#" alt="Preview" class="file-image hidden">
    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/online-states/150/Snooze-512.png" class="error-image hidden">
    <div class="start">
      <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <div>Select a file or drag here</div>
      <div class="notimage hidden">Please select an image</div>
    </div>
    <div class="response hidden">
      <div class="messages"></div>
    </div>
  </label>
  </form>
  <div class="filename"></div>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. This could use to be cleaned up a bit, but it should put you in the right direction.

Sorry for not explaining the changes I made in detail, but there are a lot of them so please just compare your code to mine to see what's different.

```js
// File Upload
//
$(function() {
  console.log("_________________________");

  $(".file-drag").click(function(event) {
    $(this)
      .siblings(".file-upload")
      .click();
  });

  function ekUpload(item) {

    var form = $(this).find('form.uploader'),
      fileSelect = $(this).find(".file-upload"),
      fileDrag = $(this).find(".file-drag"),
      submitButton = $(this).find(".submit-button");

    function Init() {
      // console.log("Init()");

      // fileSelect.addEventListener("change", fileSelectHandler, false);
      $(document).on('change', 'form', function(e) {
        fileSelectHandler(e);
      });

      // Is XHR2 available?
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      if (xhr.upload) {
        // File Drop
        // fileDrag.addEventListener("dragover", fileDragHover, false);
        // fileDrag.addEventListener("dragleave", fileDragHover, false);
        // fileDrag.addEventListener("drop", fileSelectHandler, false);

        if (isAdvancedUpload) {

          $(document).on('drag dragstart dragend dragover dragenter dragleave', 'form', function(e) {
              // fileDragHover(e);
              e.preventDefault();
              e.stopPropagation();
            })
            .on('dragover dragenter', 'form', function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              e.stopPropagation();
              $(e.target).addClass('is-dragover');
            })
            .on('dragleave dragend drop', 'form', function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              e.stopPropagation();
              $(e.target).removeClass('is-dragover');
            })
            .on('drop dragover', 'body', function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              e.stopPropagation();
            })
            .on('drop', 'form', function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              e.stopPropagation();
              fileSelectHandler(e);
            });

        }
      }
    }

    function fileDragHover(e) {
      // var fileDrag = $(".file-drag");

      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();

      e.target.className =
        e.type === "dragover" ? "hover" : "modal-body file-upload";
    }

    async function fileSelectHandler(e) {

      var theForm = $(e.target).parent('form.uploader');

      // var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;      
      var files = e.target.files || e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;

      // Process all File objects
      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        const f = files[i];
        if (await hasAlpha(f)) {
          console.log("Selected image is transparent");
          parseFile(f, theForm);
          uploadFile(f, theForm);
        } else {
          console.log("Selected image is not transparent");
          // document.querySelector(".response").classList.remove("hidden");
          // document.querySelector(".error-image").classList.remove("hidden");
          // document.querySelector(".file-image").classList.add("hidden");
          $(theForm)
            .find(".response, .error-image, .file-image")
            .removeClass("hidden");
          output(
            '<strong class="warning">Image background is not transparent</strong>'
          );
        }
      }
    }

    // Output
    function output(msg) {
      // Response
      // var m = document.getElementById("messages");
      var m = $(item).find(".messages");
      // m.innerHTML = msg;
      m.html(msg);
    }

    function hasAlpha(file) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let hasAlpha = false;
        const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        const img = new Image();
        img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
        img.onerror = reject;
        img.onload = function() {
          canvas.width = img.width;
          canvas.height = img.height;

          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
          const imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
            .data;

          for (let j = 0; j < imgData.length; j += 4) {
            if (imgData[j + 3] < 255) {
              hasAlpha = true;
              break;
            }
          }
          resolve(hasAlpha);
        };
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      });
    }

    function parseFile(file, thisForm) {
      console.log(file.name);
      output("<strong>" + encodeURI(file.name) + "</strong>");

      // var fileType = file.type;
      // console.log(fileType);
      var imageName = file.name;

      var isGood = /\.(?=svg|jpg|png|jpeg)/gi.test(imageName);
      if (isGood) {
        // document.getElementById("start").classList.add("hidden");
        // document.getElementById("response").classList.remove("hidden");
        // document.getElementById("notimage").classList.add("hidden");
        $(thisForm)
          .find(".start", ".notimage")
          .addClass("hidden");
        $(thisForm)
          .find(".response")
          .removeClass("hidden");
        // Thumbnail Preview
        // document.querySelector("#error-image").classList.add("hidden");
        // document.getElementById("file-image").classList.remove("hidden");
        // document.getElementById("file-image").src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        $(thisForm)
          .find(".error-image")
          .addClass("hidden");
        $(thisForm).find('label.has-advanced-upload').removeClass('has-advanced-upload');
        $(thisForm)
          .find(".file-image")
          .removeClass("hidden")
          .attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(file));
      } else {
        // document.querySelector("#error-image").classList.remove("hidden");
        // document.getElementById("file-image").classList.add("hidden");
        // document.getElementById("notimage").classList.remove("hidden");
        // document.getElementById("start").classList.remove("hidden");
        // document.getElementById("response").classList.add("hidden");
        // document.getElementById("file-upload-form").reset();
        $(thisForm)
          .find(".error-image, .notimage, .start")
          .removeClass("hidden");
        $(thisForm)
          .find(".file-image, .response")
          .addClass("hidden");
        $(thisForm)
          .find(".file-upload-form")
          .trigger("reset");
        $(thisForm).find('label[for="file-upload"]').addClass('has-advanced-upload');
      }
    }

    function uploadFile(file, thisForm) {
      // var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
      // fileInput = document.getElementById("class-roster-file"),
      //   fileSizeLimit = 1024; // In MB
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        // fileInput = $(item).find('.class-roster-file'),
        fileSizeLimit = 1024; // in MB

      if (xhr.upload) {
        // Check if file is less than x MB
        if (file.size <= fileSizeLimit * 1024 * 1024) {
          // File received / failed
          xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
              // Everything is good!
              // document.location.reload(true);
              console.log("everything is good");
            }
          };

          // Start upload
          xhr.open(
            "POST",
            // document.getElementById("file-upload-form").action,
            $(thisForm)
            .find(".file-upload-form")
            .attr("action"),
            true
          );
          xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.size);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
          xhr.send(file);
        } else {
          output("Please upload a smaller file (< " + fileSizeLimit + " MB).");
        }
      }
    }

    // Check for the various File API support.
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
      Init();
    } else {
      document.getElementById("file-drag").style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  var isAdvancedUpload = (function() {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    return (
      ("draggable" in div || ("ondragstart" in div && "ondrop" in div)) &&
      "FormData" in window &&
      "FileReader" in window
    );
  })();

  if (isAdvancedUpload) {
    $('.file-drag').addClass('has-advanced-upload');
  }

  $(".item").each(function() {
    ekUpload(this);
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto");
html, body, * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #454cad;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

p {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #5f6982;
}

.uploader {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
}
.uploader label {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 3px solid #eee;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.uploader label.has-advanced-upload {
  background-color: white;
  outline: 2px dashed lightgrey;
  outline-offset: -10px;
}

.uploader label:hover {
  border: 3px solid #454cad;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 6px #eee;
}
.uploader label.is-dragover,
.uploader label.is-dragover:hover {
  background-color: #eef;
}

.uploader label:hover {
  border: 3px solid #454cad;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 6px #eee;
}
.uploader label:hover .start i.fa {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
          transform: scale(0.8);
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.uploader .start {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.uploader .start.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.uploader .start i.fa {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.uploader .response {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}
.uploader .response.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.uploader .response .messages {
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}
.uploader .file-image {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto .5rem auto;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 180px;
}
.uploader .file-image.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.uploader .notimage {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}
.uploader .notimage.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.uploader progress,
.uploader .progress {
  display: inline;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 180px;
  height: 8px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.uploader .progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.uploader .progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #393f90 0%, #454cad 50%);
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.uploader .progress[value]::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #393f90 0%, #454cad 50%);
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.uploader input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}
.uploader div {
  margin: 0 0 .5rem 0;
  color: #5f6982;
}
.uploader .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: .5rem .5rem 1rem .5rem;
  clear: both;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: initial;
  border: none;
  border-radius: .2rem;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #454cad;
  border-color: #454cad;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.uploader input[type="file"],
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

input[type="file"].hidden {
  display: block;
  width: 0.1px;
  height: 0.1px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.warning {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Upload  -->
<div class="item">
  <form class="file-upload-form uploader">
    <input class="file-upload" type="file" name="fileUpload" accept="image/*" />
    <label for="file-upload" class="file-drag">   
     <img class="file-image hidden" src="#" alt="Preview">
     <img class="error-image hidden" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/online-states/150/Snooze-512.png">
     <div class="start">
       <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       <div>Select a file or drag here</div>
       <div class="notimage hidden">Please select an image</div>
     </div>
     <div class="response hidden">
       <div class="messages"></div>
     </div>
   </label>
  </form>
  <div class="filename"></div>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <form class="file-upload-form uploader">
    <input class="file-upload" type="file" name="fileUpload" accept="image/*" />
    <label for="file-upload" class="file-drag">   
     <img class="file-image hidden" src="#" alt="Preview">
     <img class="error-image hidden" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/online-states/150/Snooze-512.png">
     <div class="start">
       <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       <div>Select a file or drag here</div>
       <div class="notimage hidden">Please select an image</div>
     </div>
     <div class="response hidden">
       <div class="messages"></div>
     </div>
   </label>
  </form>
  <div class="filename"></div>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @thingEvery I noticed that the `else` conditions on `if (isGood) {}` are not working specifically for adding and removing the `hidden` class.

Comment: @KyleUnderhill Are you sure? Because I just changed `if (isGood)` to `if (!isGood)` to test it and saw that `.file-image` & `.response` had the `hidden` class and `.error-image`, `.notimage`, and `.start` did not.

Comment: when you upload an image with a background, it should trigger the else portion of the `if (isgood)` which should be giving the `hidden` class to the `.file-image`. Also if you then upload a transparent image and then another one with background you will see that the `.file-image` doesn't receive the `hidden` class.

Comment: @KyleUnderhill This is incorrect. If you upload a non-transparent image, the `if (isGood)` conditional is never executed. You are calling `hasAlpha()` in `fileSelectHandler()`. If it returns `false`, you are not calling `parseFile()` which is where the `.hidden` class would be added to `.file-image`.

Comment: I tried moving the else conditions from `if (isGood) {}` to the else in `fileSelectHandler(e)` in order to hide the elements that aren't the error but it also doesn't seem to fire

Comment: @KyleUnderhill Maybe start a new question with your updated code.

Answer (score 0):

The code has multiple issues, most important ones are:

1. You are not providing correct id for placeholder label (for="file-upload")
2. It is registering for events multiple time
3. You are not providing an individual file control but rather list of it
4. Similarly, in many places code is executing functions on an array, which should be executed on HTML object

I have updated you code and it seems to be working. However, you still might have to test it.

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fpuo5xtv/), FYI.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function ekUpload($item) {
    function fileDragHover(e) {
      var fileDrag = $item.find(".file-drag");

      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();

      fileDrag.className =
        e.type === "dragover" ? "hover" : "modal-body file-upload";
    }

    async function fileSelectHandler(e) {
      // Fetch FileList object
      var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

      // Cancel event and hover styling
      fileDragHover(e);

      // Process all File objects
      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        const f = files[i];
        if (await hasAlpha(f)) {
          console.log("Selected image is transparent");
          parseFile(f);
          uploadFile(f);
        } else {
          console.log("Selected image is not transparent");
          $item.find(".response").removeClass("hidden");
          $item.find(".error-image").removeClass("hidden");
          $item.find(".file-image").addClass("hidden");
          output(
            '<strong class="warning">Image background is not transparent</strong>'
          );
        }
      }
    }
    // Output
    function output(msg) {
      // Response
      var m = $item.find(".messages");
      m.innerHTML = msg;
    }

    function Init() {
      console.log("Upload Initialised");

      var fileSelect = $item.find(".file-upload"),
        fileDrag = $item.find(".file-drag"),
        submitButton = $item.find(".submit-button");

      fileSelect.on("change", function(e) {
        fileSelectHandler(e);
      });

      // Is XHR2 available?
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      if (xhr.upload) {
        // File Drop
        fileDrag.on("change dragleave", function(e) {
          fileDragHover(e);
        });
        fileDrag.on("drop", function(e) {
          fileSelectHandler(e);
        });
      }
    }

    function hasAlpha(file) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let hasAlpha = false;
        const canvas = $item.find("canvas")[0];
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        const img = new Image();
        img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
        img.onerror = reject;
        img.onload = function() {
          canvas.width = img.width;
          canvas.height = img.height;

          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
          const imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
            .data;

          for (let j = 0; j < imgData.length; j += 4) {
            if (imgData[j + 3] < 255) {
              hasAlpha = true;
              break;
            }
          }
          resolve(hasAlpha);
        };
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      });
    }

    function parseFile(file) {
      console.log(file.name);
      output("<strong>" + encodeURI(file.name) + "</strong>");

      // var fileType = file.type;
      // console.log(fileType);
      var imageName = file.name;

      var isGood = /\.(?=svg|jpg|png|jpeg)/gi.test(imageName);
      if (isGood) {
        $item.find(".start").addClass("hidden");
        $item.find(".response").removeClass("hidden");
        $item.find(".notimage").addClass("hidden");
        // Thumbnail Preview
        $item.find(".error-image").addClass("hidden");
        $item.find(".file-image").removeClass("hidden");
        $item.find(".file-image").src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      } else {
        $item.find(".error-image").removeClass("hidden");
        $item.find(".file-image").addClass("hidden");
        $item.find(".notimage").removeClass("hidden");
        $item.find(".start").removeClass("hidden");
        $item.find(".response").addClass("hidden");
        $item.find(".file-upload-form").reset();
      }
    }

    function uploadFile(file) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        fileInput = $this.find(".class-roster-file"),
        fileSizeLimit = 1024; // In MB

      if (xhr.upload) {
        // Check if file is less than x MB
        if (file.size <= fileSizeLimit * 1024 * 1024) {
          // File received / failed
          xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
              // Everything is good!
              // document.location.reload(true);
            }
          };

          // Start upload
          xhr.open(
            "POST",
            document.getElementById("file-upload-form").action,
            true
          );
          xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.size);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
          xhr.send(file);
        } else {
          output("Please upload a smaller file (< " + fileSizeLimit + " MB).");
        }
      }
    }

    // Check for the various File API support.
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
      Init();
    } else {
      $item.find("file-drag").css("display", "none");
    }
  }
  $(".item").each(function(idx, item) {
    ekUpload($(item));
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto");
html,
body,
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #454cad;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

p {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #5f6982;
}

.uploader {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.uploader label {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 3px solid #eee;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.uploader label:hover {
  border-color: #454cad;
}

.uploader label.hover {
  border: 3px solid #454cad;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 6px #eee;
}

.uploader label.hover #start i.fa {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  transform: scale(0.8);
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.uploader #start {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

.uploader #start.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.uploader #start i.fa {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.uploader #response {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

.uploader #response.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.uploader #response #messages {
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

.uploader #file-image {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto .5rem auto;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 180px;
}

.uploader #file-image.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.uploader #notimage {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

.uploader #notimage.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.uploader progress,
.uploader .progress {
  display: inline;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 180px;
  height: 8px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.uploader .progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.uploader .progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #393f90 0%, #454cad 50%);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.uploader .progress[value]::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #393f90 0%, #454cad 50%);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.uploader input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}

.uploader div {
  margin: 0 0 .5rem 0;
  color: #5f6982;
}

.uploader .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: .5rem .5rem 1rem .5rem;
  clear: both;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: initial;
  border: none;
  border-radius: .2rem;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #454cad;
  border-color: #454cad;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.uploader input[type="file"],
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.warning {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <form class="uploader file-upload-form">
   <input id="fu1" class="file-upload" type="file" name="fileUpload" accept="image/*" />
   <label for="fu1" class="file-drag">
    <img src="#" alt="Preview" class="file-image hidden">
    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/online-states/150/Snooze-512.png" class="error-image hidden">
    <div class="start">
     <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     <div>Select a file or drag here</div>
     <div class="notimage hidden">Please select an image</div>
    </div>
    <div class="response hidden">
     <div class="messages"></div>
    </div>
   </label>
  </form>
  <div class="filename"></div>
  <canvas></canvas>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
   <form class="uploader file-upload-form">
  <input id="fu2" class="file-upload" type="file" name="fileUpload" accept="image/*" />
  <label for="fu2" class="file-drag">
   <img src="#" alt="Preview" class="file-image hidden">
   <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/online-states/150/Snooze-512.png" class="error-image hidden">
   <div class="start">
    <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <div>Select a file or drag here</div>
    <div class="notimage hidden">Please select an image</div>
   </div>
   <div class="response hidden">
    <div class="messages"></div>
   </div>
  </label>
   </form>
   <div class="filename"></div>
   <canvas></canvas>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hi @Dipen Shah, the function works in the Javascript demo set up in the codepen. Our jQuery code does not work as intended in the codepen.

Comment: @KyleUnderhillI am not sure about that, I just fixed few things I missed when I posted first.

Comment: @KyleUnderhill Added jsfiddle link for your information.

Comment: It looks like you have figured out the main function but you can see in this codepen that the other functions like image preview, drag and drop, and error message aren't firing in the Fiddle: https://codepen.io/moofawsaw/pen/dyPdpGy

Comment: That is because, I haven't completely solved your code issues. I am helping you to figure out changes you might need to do in order to fix your converted code. For started, you have used find in many places, you might want to check results of find as it is an array of html objects and not an object it self.